# SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, break

Мне нужно создать Меню утилиты, чтобы при вводе 9 у меня открывалось второе меню, которое также запускалось заново при выборе какой либо функции, а не вылетало, но выдаёт ошибку D:>python 4ist1k.py
File "D:\4ist1k.py", line 69
break
^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Вот сам код:

```
clear = input("Выберите пункт: ")
#-Начало-функций-очистки
if clear == "1":
    print('[!] Очистка файла...')

elif clear == "2":
    print(wrn, "Очистка истории")
elif clear == "0":
    break
else:
    print("Вы ввели неправильное значение...")
```

Здесь без функций, чтобы было кратко

Comment: `break` можно использовать только внутри цикла. Что должно происходить если `clear=="0"`? Зачем вы там используете `break`?

Comment: если это функция - то вместо `break` нужен `return`

Comment: Использую `break` для того, чтобы выйти из программы

Comment: чел, откуда ты взял, что break выходит из программы?.....

Comment: Я всего лишь учусь, так что извиняюсь

Comment: чтобы выйти из программы используйте `exit()`

Answer (score 1):

`break` можно использовать только в цикле для досрочного прерывания цикла.

Чтобы прекратить выполнение условного оператора, надо обернуть его в функцию

```py
user_clear = input("Выберите пункт: ")

def check_user_input(clear):
    if clear == "1":
        print('[!] Очистка файла...')
    elif clear == "2":
        print(wrn, "Очистка истории")
    elif clear == "0":
        return  # завершает функцию
    else:
        print("Вы ввели неправильное значение...")

check_user_input(user_clear)
```

Чтобы выйти из программы можно использовать `raise SystemExit(0)`

Comment: Очень сильно благодарю

Comment: Да, всё работает, огромное спасибо!